# What is the meaning of the word “larriking”?

Tags: meaning, etymology

From “Holiday Memory” in  *Quite Early One Morning* by Dylan Thomas

> Lolling or larriking that unsoiled, boiling beauty of a common day, great gods with their braces over their vests sang, spat pips, puffed smoke at wasps, gulped and ogled, forgot the rent, embraced, posed for the dicky bird, were coarse, had rainbow-coloured arm-pits, winked, belched, blamed the radishes, looked at Ilfracombe, played hymns on paper and comb, peeled bananas, scratched, found seaweed in their panamas, blew up paper-bags and banged them, wished for nothing.

I searched the word in Google and in the Thesaurus but that didn’t help much. Could anyone provide the meaning and possibly the etymology of the word?

Comment: Dylan Thomas likely made it up. Either that or it was Welsh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *larrikin* is an Irish/Australian word for the sort of young man who goes about drinking, getting into scrapes,and perhaps fighting; but it's usually used indulgently, in a 'we've all been young' sort of way. Probably Dylan Thomas adapted it; the meaning is clear enough, even though there may be no recognizable etymology.

Comment: "... no recognisable etymology": unless, as seems logical, it derives from 'lark'.

Comment: @fortunate1: Maybe Dylan Thomas saw a connection with "larking [about]", but OED doesn't mention that as a possibility (they say the origin is "uncertain", but may come from the name "Larry").

Answer (score 2):

The spelling is given as *larrikin* in [*On the Air with Dylan Thomas: The Broadcasts*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=aE7eS_vRXS0C&pg=PA137&dq=%E2%80%9CHoliday%20Memory%E2%80%9D%20Dylan%20Thomas&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BoOJUKSKM-bl4QSJ1YGACg&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=larrikin&f=false) rather than *larriking* of *[Quite Early One Morning](http://books.google.fi/books?id=KWOfkWlBmBUC&pg=PA22&dq=%E2%80%9CHoliday%20Memory%E2%80%9D%20Dylan%20Thomas&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BoOJUKSKM-bl4QSJ1YGACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=larriking&f=false)*. The former book says:

> After its broadcast on the Third Programme on 25 October 1946, 'Holiday Memory' was referred to by N. G. Luker, Assistant Director of Talks, as 'one of the half dozen best talks I have ever heard' (memo to the producer, James Langham). Thomas was asked to re-read it for the BBC Archives on 6 December 1946; that reading survives and has been used to confirm the accuracy of the present text, based on the BBC script and the printing in *The Listener* (7 November 1946).

The OED says of *larrikin*:

> **Etymology:**  Of uncertain origin; possibly < *Larry* (a nickname for Lawrence, common in Ireland) + -kin *suffix*.
>
> The word seems to have originated in Melbourne not long before 1870; but the story that it was evolved by a reporter from an Irish policeman's pronunciation of *larking*, heard in a Melbourne police-court in 1869, appears to be a figment, no trace of the incident being found in the local papers of the time. (See Morris, *Austral Eng.*, s.v.) A guess that has been proposed is that it is short for English slang *leary kinchen*. Wright, *Suppl. to Eng. Dial. Dict.*, cites *larrikin* ‘a mischievous or frolicsome youth’ from informants in Warwickshire and Worcestershire; see also quot. 1882 at sense a. Compare *Eng. Dial. Dict.*, Larack (*larack about*, to ‘lark’ about), cited from C. C. Robinson's *Dial. Leeds & Neighbourhood* (1861).

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: (larack about, to ‘lark’ about), cited from C. C. Robinson's Dial. Leeds & Neighbourhood (1861). (evidently ff/aka larry & I have a different understanding of English etymology ...but of course, more points evidence his credibility, if not this site's.)

Comment: @fortunate1: If you think the verb *larack about* and the noun *larrikin* are identical, your understanding of etymology is indeed unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, I consulted Warrack's *Concise Scots Dictionary*. Thus:

Larick, *n.* the lark, 'laverock'

[and, just because I'm on that page, and because it's fun: 
Larick's lint, *n.* the great golden maidenhair, Cf. Laverock's-lint]

So, I assume Thomas's meaning is that the gods are gamboling, playing joyfully about.

Comment: Interesting. Do Scots words turn up in Welsh? The definition certainly seems to fit the context.

Comment: If I had a Welsh dictionary, JAMy, I could answer you!

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely Thomas's usage owes anything at all to  *Larick - lark [the bird]*.

Comment: ... because why; your snide "Larry" remark above is unhelpful.

Comment: What's "snide" about quoting OED? I'll also point out that your "lark" definition isn't in OED (they say *larick* is a mistaken back-formation from Scottish *larix = **larch***, which was always singular anyway). Also note that Thomas definitely isn't talking about "the gods" as such - he's talking about the idle young men of the area, *with their braces over their vests*, etc.